# Store non existence column in JPA entity when it is used as Alias in SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have written query to count the number of locations available under a specified enterprise. The SQL Query goes like this

```
SELECT 
e.enterprise_id,
e.ent_name,
(
    SELECT count(l.location_id)
    FROM rfx_ent_locations l
    WHERE l.loc_type_id <> 1001
        AND e.enterprise_id = l.enterprise_id
) AS locCount
FROM rfx_enterprises e
WHERE  e.partner_type = 102;
```

If introduce as a column in entity , I get a error saying no column found. To retrieve as entity including locCount which is used as alias, using JPA how should I proceed?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you trying to run this query via EntityManager.createNativeQuery?  If so, not sure what "retrieve as entity" means.

Comment: @SteveEbersole : If i write as native query I need to assign to an entity class. The result of the native query is assigned to entity with the column mapped. Additionally if I have extra column like locCount how can I map?

Answer (score 0):

Dont do your count query with that.do it separately like this

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT count(l.location_id)
    FROM rfx_ent_locations l
    WHERE l.loc_type_id <> 1001
        AND e.enterprise_id = l.enterprise_id");// do as you please with the query result

    /**
     * instead of doing a second query to get the count.  Just do a quick count using Iterator
     */

    for (Iterator iterator = query.iterate(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        iterator.next();
        count++;
    }

    Integer queryCount = count;
```

set this queryCount to your **@transient** varible setter method in your class.so you can have your count

**or**
try like this

```
Integer count = (Integer) session.CreateQuery("SELECT count(l.location_id)
FROM rfx_ent_locations l
WHERE l.loc_type_id <> 1001
    AND e.enterprise_id = l.enterprise_id").UniqueResult();
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Both the methods won't work. Result can't be set to "@transient" variable. And the second query will return the total number of records available.